# Shortcut to jump between words/phrases separated by spaces in a terminal

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

When we write commands especially long ones, we sometimes need to make edits. For example imagine:

```
docker run --rm --name My_container_3.19.2.9-999_khbdabshs --entrypoint bash registry.me.com:2001/apps/My_container_3.19.2.9-999_khbdabshs
```

Starting at the beginning of the line by hitting `ctrl+a` or end of line by hitting `ctrl+e`, how can I quickly get to the word `bash`?

Is there a shortcut to jump between `docker` `run` `--rm` `--name` `My_container_3.19.2.9-999_khbdabshs` `--entrypoint` `bash` `registry.me.com:2001/apps/My_container_3.19.2.9-999_khbdabshs`, which are all seperated by spaces?

I've seen people mention `ctrl+b/f` or `esc+b/f` but it doesn't exactly do what I want.

I'm using iTerm with ZSH on a macOS. Hopefully the shortcut works irrespective to what emulator or shell I use.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> will jump one "word" **F**orward.

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> will jump one "word" **B**ackward.

On many modern keyboards, <kbd>Alt</kbd> works as <kbd>Meta</kbd>.  On a Mac, it may be <kbd>Option</kbd>  You can also use <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd>. For the latter iterations, it is not a key *combination*, but a key *sequence*:  Press and release <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then press and release either <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> followed by any character to jump the cursor rightward to the next match for the specified character.  So if your cursor is at the start of the line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> three times would place the cursor at the `b` in `bash`.

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> followed by any character to jump the cursor leftward similarly.